# Containerized databases cannot be accessed from containerized apps

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a project consisting of containerized docker applications in both .Net and Java. As can be seen from my compose file, each application has its own database.

My problem is that when i run all the containers with compose up, my applications cannot access the databases. However, when i run the databases as containers, and the applications from their respective local runtime installations on my PC (dotnet/java) my applications connect to the databases just fine. I suspect that there is some network related configuration in my compose file that im not aware of, which is causing the trouble. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what i am doing wrong?

**Error messages**

*Java app*

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

*.Net app*

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  identity.api:
    image: unify/identity.api:${TAG-latest}
    build:
      context: ./src/Services/IdentityService/src
    env_file:
      - 'aspnetcore.env'
    ports:
      - 5000:80

  course.api:
    image: unify/course.api:${TAG-latest}
    build:
      context: ./src/Services/CourseService/src
    env_file:
      - 'aspnetcore.env'
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    depends_on:
      - "course.data"
      - "identity.api"

  course.data:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password
    volumes:
      - course.data.volume:/var/opt/mssql

  message.api:
    image: unify/message.api:${TAG-latest}
    build:
      context: ./src/Services/MessageService
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - "message.data"

  message.data:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw
    volumes:
      - message.data.volume:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  course.data.volume:
  message.data.volume:
```

Comment: Your error means that the server is not found. From what you wrote I understood that you can connect locally but cannot connect remotely, am I right? Did you check your server protocols(other than shared memory) if they are enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:1433
```

The loopback interface is namespaced in a docker container, each container will get it's own private loopback that is separate from the host and from other containers. To perform container to container networking:

1. change the destination to the container name, or compose service name
2. connect to the container port, not the port you publish on the host
3. place the containers on the same docker network. For DNS resolution in step 1 to work, make sure that network is not the default bridge network named "bridge". You get this step for free when you create everything in the same compose file and use version 2 or 3.

What this means is you just need to reconfigure your app to connect to "course.data:1433" instead of "127.0.0.1:1433".

Comment: Thank you. By interchanging localhost with the container names of the databases, it works perfectly.